# Multiple submit buttons in the same form calling different Servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

First, here is the code:

```
<form action="FirstServlet" method="Post">
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" size="20">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="FirstServlet">
    <input type="submit"value="SecondServlet">
</form>
```

I'd like to understand how to send information in case the `FirstServlet button` was pressed to `FirstServlet` and in case the `SecondServlet button` was pressed to `SecondServlet`.

**important:**
I want to do it in the same form so the same information would be transered to both the servlets. (of course, in the servlets I'll use the info accordingly)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.

Probably the easiest would be to use JavaScript to change the form's action.

```html
<input type="submit" value="SecondServlet" onclick="form.action='SecondServlet';">
```

But this of course won't work when the enduser has JS disabled (mobile browsers, screenreaders, etc).

---

Another way is to put the second button in a different form, which may or may not be what you need, depending on the concrete functional requirement, which is not clear from the question at all.

```html
<form action="FirstServlet" method="Post">
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" size="20">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="FirstServlet">
</form>
<form action="SecondServlet" method="Post">
    <input type="submit"value="SecondServlet">
</form>
```

Note that a form would on submit only send the input data contained in the very same form, not in the other form.

---

Again another way is to just create another single entry point servlet which delegates further to the right servlets (or preferably, the right business actions) depending on the button pressed (which is by itself available as a request parameter by its `name`):

```html
<form action="MainServlet" method="Post">
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" size="20">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="FirstServlet">
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="SecondServlet">
</form>
```

with the following in `MainServlet`

```
String action = request.getParameter("action");

if ("FirstServlet".equals(action)) {
    // Invoke FirstServlet's job here.
} else if ("SecondServlet".equals(action)) {
    // Invoke SecondServlet's job here.
}
```

This is only not very i18n/maintenance friendly. What if you need to show buttons in a different language or change the button values while forgetting to take the servlet code into account?

---

A slight change is to give the buttons its own fixed and unique name, so that its presence as request parameter could be checked instead of its value which would be sensitive to i18n/maintenance:

```html
<form action="MainServlet" method="Post">
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" size="20">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="first" value="FirstServlet">
    <input type="submit" name="second" value="SecondServlet">
</form>
```

with the following in `MainServlet`

```
if (request.getParameter("first") != null) {
    // Invoke FirstServlet's job here.
} else if (request.getParameter("second") != null) {
    // Invoke SecondServlet's job here.
}
```

---

Last way would be to just use a MVC framework like [JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) so that you can directly bind javabean methods to buttons, but that would require drastic changes to your existing code.

```html
<h:form>
    Last Name: <h:inputText value="#{bean.lastName}" size="20" />
    <br/><br/>
    <h:commandButton value="First" action="#{bean.first}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Second" action="#{bean.Second}" />
</h:form>
```

with just the following javabean instead of a servlet

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    private String lastName; // +getter+setter

    public void first() {
        // Invoke original FirstServlet's job here.
    }

    public void second() {
        // Invoke original SecondServlet's job here.
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, very comprehensive answer!

Comment: @BalusC Can you explain how to invoke the servlet  I tried like this `RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/servletName");
   rd.forward(request, response);`.But it not working

Comment: @spt: pass servlet path (matching the URL pattern), not servlet name.

Comment: @BalusC getting the following http response _HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL_

Comment: @spt: That's already an answer at its own. It's at least not related to the current question. If you don't understand it, just copypaste the error message into the input field of a search engine (e.g. Google or the input field on right top here at Stack Overflow).

Comment: @BalusC when i am doing action on button the url changed to _http://localhost:8080/Project/?UploadFile=Upload_. And here it is not getting the data. I have two servlets one having upload file and other is drop selection. i am using three buttons,one for uploading the file, other for generating the report based on the drop down selection.Here i am getting the name of the button **Upload**

Comment: Nice answer...! I had a similar question, will try this solution

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the previous response, the best option to submit a form with different buttons without language problems is actually using a **button** tag.

```
<form>
    ...
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="servlet1">Go to 1st Servlet</button>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="servlet2">Go to 2nd Servlet</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use jQuery,  u can do it like this:

```
<form action="example" method="post" id="loginform">
  ...
  <input id="btnin" type="button" value="login"/>
  <input id="btnreg" type="button" value="regist"/>
</form>
```

And js will be:

```
$("#btnin").click(function(){
   $("#loginform").attr("action", "user_login");
   $("#loginform").submit();
}
$("#btnreg").click(function(){
   $("#loginform").attr("action", "user_regist");
   $("#loginform").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to write a javascript for each button submit. Instead of defining action in form definition, set those values in javascript. Something like below.

```
function callButton1(form, yourServ)
{
form.action = yourServ;
form.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

***If*** you use spring this a better way

[Is there any way to create form with multiple submit buttons on Spring MVC using annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631262/is-there-any-way-to-create-form-with-multiple-submit-buttons-on-spring-mvc-using)

Answer (score 0):

```
    function gotofirst(){
        window.location = "firstServelet.java";
}
    function gotosecond(){
        window.location = "secondServelet.java";
}
```

```html
<form action="FirstServlet" method="Post">
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" size="20">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" onclick="gotofirst()" value="FirstServlet">
    <input type="submit" onclick="gotosecond()" value="SecondServlet">
</form>
```