# How to decode commandButton action

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I've been studying how to develop JSF custom components to improve my knowledge about how it works (it's been quite interesting so far).

I made my own commandButton (extended from HtmlCommandButton) and it worked as expected when doing all decoding and enconding in the component class.

When I decided to create a separated faces renderer for my component it stopped working. After some research I learned that I had to override the decode method of my renderer and it was working before just because this method was already implemented by HtmlCommandButton.

After some research I found out how to decode action listeners ([thanks to BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837049/how-does-jsf-process-action-listener)) and I also learnt how to decode ajax events. However I still didn't know how to decode actions.

This is my decode method right now:

```
@Override
public void decode(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
    CommandButtonUI commandButton = (CommandButtonUI) component;
    //decode click ajax events
    List<ClientBehavior> clientBehaviours = commandButton.getClientBehaviors().get("click");
    if (clientBehaviours != null) {
        for (ClientBehavior cb : clientBehaviours) {
            cb.decode(context, component);
        }
    }
    //decode action listenet
    if (context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().containsKey(commandButton.getClientId(context))) {
        component.queueEvent(new ActionEvent(component));
    }
}
```

I already tried to find HtmlCommandButton's decode source and analyse it, but I failed to find it, since apparently it's generated by a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i do it. But don't got forget: 1) to add the `@FacesRenderer` annotation to your render class with the respective `componentFamily` and `rendererType` values. 
2) to define your component RenderType on your component class using `setRendererType` in the class constructor.

```java
public void decode(FacesContext pContext, UIComponent pComponent) {
    YourComponent xButton = (DBSButton) pComponent;         
    String        xClientId = xButton.getClientId(); 
    if(xButton.getReadOnly()) {return;}

    decodeBehaviors(pContext, xButton);

    if (RenderKitUtils.isPartialOrBehaviorAction(pContext, xClientId)    
     || pContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().containsKey(xClientId)) {
        xButton.queueEvent(new ActionEvent(xButton));    
    }
}

protected void decodeBehaviors(FacesContext pContext, UIComponent pComponent)
{
    if(!(pComponent instanceof ClientBehaviorHolder)) {
        return;
    }

    Map<String, List<ClientBehavior>> xBehaviors = ((ClientBehaviorHolder) pComponent).getClientBehaviors();
    if(xBehaviors.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    Map<String, String> xParams = pContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String xBehaviorEvent = xParams.get("javax.faces.behavior.event");

    if(null != xBehaviorEvent) {
        List<ClientBehavior> xBehaviorsForEvent = xBehaviors.get(xBehaviorEvent);

        if(xBehaviorsForEvent != null && !xBehaviorsForEvent.isEmpty()) {
           String xBehaviorSource = xParams.get("javax.faces.source");
           String xClientId = pComponent.getClientId();

           if(xBehaviorSource != null && xClientId.startsWith(xBehaviorSource)) {
               for(ClientBehavior xBehavior: xBehaviorsForEvent) {
                   xBehavior.decode(pContext, pComponent);
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm stil trying to understand it (it seems it just follows step-by-step what's specified in the renderkit documentation for the decode behaviour), but it worked for me. Thanks. ^^