# Invoking different methods via Servlets depending upon a URL

Tags: jsp, url, servlets

I would like invoking methods based on URL mappings using Servlet/JSP.

A Servlet is mapped to a pattern like `/xxx/*`. I have created an interface with only one method as follows.

```
public interface Action
{
   public void execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, SQLException, ServletException, IOException;
}
```

A `java.util.Map` initialized with different implementations of this interface to perform different actions based on a URL in the Servlet we are talking about in its `init()` method as follows.

```
@WebServlet(name = "Country", urlPatterns = {"/Country/*"})
public final class Country extends HttpServlet
{
    private Map<String, Action>map;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
    {
        super.init(config);
        map=new HashMap<String, Action>();

        map.put("Create", new CreateAction());
        map.put("Read", new ReadAction());
        map.put("Delete", new DeleteAction());
        map.put("Edit", new EditAction());
    }
}
```

The `execute()` method is invoked precisely from either the `doGet()` or `doPost()` method just like as follows.

```
map.get(request.getPathInfo().substring(1)).execute(request, response);
```

For instance, a URL like, `http://localhost:8080/Assignment/Country/Create` would invoke the `execute()` method in the `CreateAction` class.

Similarly, a URL like, `http://localhost:8080/Assignment/Country/Delete` would invoke the `execute()` method in the `DeleteAction` class and so on.

---

While using links, we can easily form a URL of our choice like,

```
<c:url var="editURL" value="/Country/Edit">
    <c:param name="countryId" value="${row.countryId}"/>
    <c:param name="currentPage" value="${currentPage}"/>
    <c:param name="countryName" value="${row.countryName}"/>
    <c:param name="countryCode" value="${row.countryCode}"/>
</c:url>

<a href="${editURL}" class="action2"/>
```

This produces a URL like `http://localhost:8080/Assignment/Country/Edit` which will call the `execute()` method in the `EditAction` class.

How to do the same while using a submit button? Can we have an appropriate URL, when a given submit button is pressed which causes the `execute()` method in the `CreateAction` class?

When pressing this submit button, the URL should be

`http://localhost:8080/Assignment/Country/Create`

The default URL to render an initial page view is like,

`http://localhost:8080/Assignment/Country`

Can we construct such URLs while making a `POST` request something similar to those provided by request/action based MVC frameworks (The Struts framework provides an `action` attribute for a submit button)?

Comment: Found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11830483/1391249) useful/helpful. More than that is unlikely to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the URL in the action attribute of the `form` element. Any button of type `submit` will post to this URL. Example:

```
<form action="${editURL}" method="post">
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

Comment: But there is more than one submit button on the form and the action is different for all of them. So how can we tackle with all of the buttons on the form? (How can we make a different request using different URLs using the `action` attribute of the form?)

Comment: Can't you have multiple forms? Otherwise, you will probably have to use javascript to dynamicaly set the URL.

Comment: If you have another better alternative then, please don't forget to update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript function on submit button and set some hidden params in your form and change the values according to your form submission and get the hidden param in your Controller. According to their hidden param values, you can use multiple operations.

Hope It'll help you.

Comment: If you have another better alternative then, please don't forget to update the answer.